# Whats wrong with this jQuery Date picker code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have been using the jQuery date picker for a while and its great. however, I'm now using it in a user control and cant get it to work failing with the error:

**Object Does Not Support This Property or Method when creating the date picker.**

My site structure is as follows:

```
[Root]
  - [Pages]
     - MasterPage.Master
     - GoodsReceived.aspx
  - [WebControls]
     - [PageControls]
       - PopupBatchEntry.ascx
```

I have added jQuery to the master page like so:

```
<link href="../App_Themes/Default/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../JavaScripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../JavaScripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../JavaScripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have added jQuery to the User control like so:

```
<script src="../../JavaScripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../JavaScripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The text boxes im trying to turn in to date pickers is in the user control inside a gridview (css class:datePicker)

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBatchDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True">
                                    <Columns>

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Use By">
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUseBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UseBy", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'
                                                    Width="80px" CssClass="datePicker"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <%--                                                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtUseBy_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                                                    Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtUseBy">
                                                </cc1:CalendarExtender>--%>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valSellByReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUseBy"
                                                    ErrorMessage="* Required" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UseBy", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sell By">
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSellBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SellBy", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'
                                                    Width="80px" CssClass="datePicker"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <%--                                                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtSellBy_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                                    Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtSellBy">
                                                </cc1:CalendarExtender>--%>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valSellByRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSellBy"
                                                    ErrorMessage="* Required" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SellBy", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity Delivered">
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantityDelivered" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuantityDelivered") %>'
                                                    Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valQuantityRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantityDelivered"
                                                    ErrorMessage="* Required" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                <asp:RangeValidator ID="valQuantityRange" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantityDelivered"
                                                    ErrorMessage="* Invalid" MinimumValue="0" Type="Double" CultureInvariantValues="True"
                                                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuantityDelivered") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <table class="BorderlessTable">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                                                                Text="Update" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                                                                Text="Cancel" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <table class="BorderlessTable">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                                                                Text="Edit" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                                                                Text="Delete" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

And finally the jQuery im using to turn the text boxes in to date pickers (in the user control):

```
//Configure dates when the page is loaded
$(document).ready(configureDates);

//Add handler toend request
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(configureDates);

//Configure all date picker text boxes
function configureDates() {

    var datePickers = $('.datePicker');

    if ($(datePickers).length > 0) {
        $(datePickers).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });   <--- ERROR IS HERE
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this? I was thinking it could be to do with the paths to the jQuery files depending on whether the current context is in the pages folder, or the web controls folder.

Comment: jQuery is perfectly capable of handling the case where a selector returns no elements - doing so yourself seems like it would gain you nothing, and simply complicates your code.

Comment: @Anthony Grist - thanks, I added that as I initially thought it was causing the issue ( the text boxes are in edit templates and dont exist on first page load). thanks for confirmation

Comment: To be honest, I think your original thought that it's a problem with the jQuery UI import is likely correct. That, or for whatever reason your jQuery UI .js file doesn't include the datePicker code. Do you have any other code in the same page that's using methods imported from that same .js file?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Just tested a single text box with the jQuery script on a flat page and it works so Im happy there is nothing wrong with the js files. Now going to drop my user control on the page and see if there are issues resolving the paths for the jquery within the control

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - ok, so I have got this working on my new flat page but I have a new issue. The z-index of the date picker is lower than the ajax control toolkit modal popup extender and it appears behind. any idea of the class i need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ResolveUrl` for your script and css refs :

```
<link href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/App_Themes/Default/Style.css")%>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/JavaScripts/jquery-ui.css")%>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/JavaScripts/jquery.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/JavaScripts/jquery-ui.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>


//Configure all date picker text boxes
function configureDates() {

    $('.datePicker').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");

}
```

Comment: Hi rick, in the master or user control? - they will resolve different paths and when viewing source for the page only one of the references is added per js file

Comment: You can add them anywhere, as long as you are using ResolveUrl they will resolve automatically, you may have to use Control.ResolveUrl.

Comment: You don't need multiple references, only one per page, so if you have them in the MasterPage, you don't need them in the controls.

Comment: Hi Rick, I have tired the page.resolveURL but now im getting the following error in base.OnInit(e) of one of my base pages (nothing is happening before this call) - the error is: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: ok, fixed the above error by moving the references to the body instead of the head.tested this and not working anyway. Ill have to create a blank page and test from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

`$(datePickers)` is a list. What should work is something like

```
$('.datePicker').each(function(idx, obj) {
    $(obj).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Pieter, I also added a standard text box to the page with the css class and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

if (datePickers.length > 0) {
        datePickers.datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });

Comment: Hi Sudhir, thanks but still not working! code changed to         var datePickers = $('.datePicker');

        if (datePickers.length > 0) {
            datePickers.datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
        }